# How to dynamically use pick()-method form UnderscoreJS

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I need to use the `pick` method from UnderscoreJS in a dynamic way like the following - please tell me why it does not work!

```
var obj = {
    one: '1',
    two: '2',
    three: '3'
};
var arr = ['one', 'two'];

var pick1 = _.pick(obj, 'one', 'two');
var pick2 = _.pick(obj, arr.toString());
console.log(pick1, pick2);
```

this returns the following:

```
Object {one: "1", two: "2"} Object {}
```

Comment: by the way: _.pick(object, *keys) returns a copy of the object, filtered to only have values for the whitelisted keys (or array of valid keys).

`_.pick({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, 'name', 'age');
=> {name: 'moe', age: 50}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're only passing a single item to `pick` (using `arr.toString()` is equivalent to calling `_.pick(obj, 'one, two')`)

Underscore.js supports passing an array to [`pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) directly ([**demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/zW8d4/)):

```
var pick2 = _.pick(obj, arr); // { one: '1', two: '2' }
```

Or you could try using the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method instead:

```
var pick2 = _.pick.apply(null, [obj].concat(arr)); // { one: '1', two: '2' }
```

Comment: Just to note - it's not required that I know of, but I generally think it's shorter and more semantically correct to use `_` as the `apply` context in these cases, instead of `null`: `_.pick.apply(_, ...)`